# Can we embed LaTeX code in HTML webpage?

Tags: html, latex2html

Is there any way to add all LaTeX code in HTML webpage? There are some ways for maths/equations but I want to use other LaTeX elements in HTML like `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Do you want to embed LaTeX *code*, or what would be rendered from it? (ie the compiled output?)

Comment: Yes, I want to embed Latex code

Comment: You can easily embed any kind of code with the `<pre>` or `<code>` tags in HTML. But I think, what you want is to embed a rendering of the LaTeX code or a conversion of the code to HTML with a similar output?

Comment: Or do you want the syntax highlighting appropriate for LaTeX code (as seen, for example, in the longer examples on this site?)